# Что отправлять на выполнение в тредпулл, runnable или thread

Tags: java, concurrency

Создал executor с единственным потоком,

```
   private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

передаю ему Thread в submit,

```
private final Thread longPollingThread = new Thread(new LongPollingThread());
```

но выходит предупреждение в SonarLint в IDEA что ожидается использование Runnable вместо Thread и так нельзя делать, но мне нужно останавливать Thread путем вызов

```
longPollingThread.interrupt();
```

а без оборачивания или унаследования от Thread Такое вызвать не получится.
в потоке я проверяю вот так

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

вопрос как мне быть, чтобы прерывать поток, можно было бы создать какой метод типа close и уже там менять boolean isStop, но зачем когда есть такая возможность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), который возвращается методом `executorService.submit(...)`, а затем вызывайте `future.cancel` с параметром `mayInterruptIfRunning` равным `true`

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Future<?> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
    int i = 0;
    System.out.print(i++);
});

future.cancel(true);
```

`Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` можно заменить на `future.isCancelled` или `future.isDone`, в зависимости от того, какую цель вы преследуете. Конкретно логику работы методов из `Future` можно прочитать по ссылке в начале моего ответа, или в javadoc, кликнув по классу `Future` с зажатой клавишей `ctrl` (перейти в реализацию класса)